# Using proxy middleware to scrape Amazon

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

```
class HttpProxyMiddleware(object):
    ###never retry these errors

    def __init__(self, settings):
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(3)

        self.proxies = []
        self.proxy_index = 1

        ##plant proxies
        self.proxy_list = settings.get('PROXY_LIST')
        fin = open(self.proxy_list)

        for line in fin.readlines():
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = 'http://%s' % line

            self.proxies.append(line)

            print self.proxies
        fin.close()

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.settings)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):

        if 'proxy' in request.meta:
            return

        if len(self.proxies) == 0:
            raise ValueError('All proxies are unusable, cannot proceed')

        proxy_address = self.proxies[self.proxy_index]
        print proxy_address

        request.meta['proxy'] = proxy_address



    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):

        print 'not working'
        self.proxy_index += 1

        new_request = request.copy()
        new_request.dont_filter = True

        return new_request
```

I have the complete proxy list from HMA and I am try to use this middleware to scrape amazon items. However, it turns out it hardly works. In 'process_request', after printing out the proxy address, it stops for a long time and eventually failed.

I also create the following program to test each proxy ip in my list. All proxy ip are working from here.

```
def main():
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(3)
    proxies = []

##plant proxies
proxy_list = '/users/zehuapan/desktop/amazon/amazon/proxy_list.txt'
fin = open(proxy_list)

for line in fin.readlines():
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = 'http://%s' % line
    print line

    if check_validity(line):
        proxies.append(line)
fin.close()

print proxies

file = open('/users/zehuapan/desktop/amazon/amazon/valid_proxy_list.txt', 'w+')
for proxy in proxies:
    file.write(proxy + '\n')
file.close()

def check_validity(proxy):

    try:
        proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy})
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        req=urllib2.Request('https://www.amazon.com')
        sock=urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print 'Error code: ', e.code
        return e.code
    except Exception, detail:
        print "ERROR:", detail
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: could you check or update your question with the errors you are getting that make the `process_exception` work? because Amazon isn't likely to return a bad status or timeout, it throws `200` status with a captcha solver which I think you are not checking

Comment: Hi<
Did this solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Zero response is unlikely to be given using a proxy. And a working proxy goes down very fast with Amazon after few hundreds of requests. 
When a proxy still works you can get a captcha page with 200 code, when it is banned you get 503 code.
Also, the proxy might work for the main page and for the offers list, but fail with the product page.
Hope that helps.